# Convert Outlook Object Model MailItemPtr to MAPI IMessage in c++

Tags: c++, encryption, outlook, mapi

Requirement: We need to create a DLL which actually decrypts my email in outlook using MAPIDEFS in c++. Our product team will pass IMessage to the DLL and I need decrypt and pass the decrypted email in the form of IMessage as an output.
This DLL will execute in different client machines.

But I failed to decrypt using mapidefs and tried using OOM and I was successfull. My OOM program takes and returns MailItemPtr as output. Now I need to convert the MailItemPtr to IMessage. Tried many ways but I could not achieve it.

Question:
Need help in converting MailItemPtr to MAPI IMessage and viceversa

Thanks for your help

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Hi Kayess, 
Thank you for your interest. We are able to decrypt a email and return it as MailItemPtr but we need output as IMessage. We are looking for a method which converts the MailItemPtr to IMessage

Answer (score 0):

Read the `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT` property - it returns IMessage MAPI object.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. I tried using MailItem.MAPIOBJECT but I could see some issue. 
Below is the snippet I am using to convert to IMessage

IUnknownPtr u = oMsg->GetMAPIOBJECT();
IMessage *msg = NULL;
msg = (IMessage*)(IUnknown*)u;
SizedSPropTagArray(1, mcols) = { 1, { PR_SENDER_NAME } };
hr = msg->GetProps((SPropTagArray*)&mcols, 0, &pcount, &props);
My program closes abruptly when it reaches GetProps method.
Seems like the conversion is not happening properly.  we are struck with this since many days and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to QI the returned IUnknown interface for IID_IMessage first.

Comment: I have tried with query Interface to get IUnknown first and then getting IMessage using that IUnknown interface. But seems the same issue.

Can you also give some hints on how to convert IMessage to MailItem

Comment: Does QI return an error? Did you call MAPIInitialize first?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I got it solved now. I have added mapi32.lib to the linker libraries and then it stared working using query interface of IUnknown first and then query Interface of IMessage. Now I could read properties from converted IMessage. 
Can you please provide some hints on converting the input IMessage to MailItem? Is that possible?
Alternatively I thought of saving the input IMessage to any folder in Inbox and which I can read it using OOM as MailItem? But I struck in saving IMessage to Inbox subfolder


Thanks for your help

Comment: Do not use a LIB file - the MAPI dlls must be loaded dynamically. See MFCMAPI source code for an example on how to do that. To reopen a message as MailItem, use Namespace.GetItemfromID.

Comment: In My case I will read the Imessage input from desktop and that mail will not be in msgstore. is it still possible to use getItemfromID

Comment: Do you mean you have IMesage from OpenIMsgOnIStg on top of an MSG file? You cannot reoerprn it in Outlook. The best you can do is call Namespace.OpenSharedItem and pass the MSG file name.

Comment: Here our product team will send IMessage to my DLL as input. So I need to convert this IMessage to OOM MailItem. 
The IMessage which product team sends is of two types 
1. From Desktop
2. From MsGStore
For the IMessage which comes from MSGStore I tried it using NameSpace.GetItemfromID with entry. 
I Struk with case 1 (IMessage read from desktop where there is no entry ID). I do not even have filepath of MSG in local machine. I need a way to convert such IMessage to MailItem
Can you give me hint to save that IMessage any inbox subfolder

Comment: You can't do anything about #1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. For 1, I tried to save back message to temp folder and from there I am reading as MailItem using OpenSharedItem.